# Laravel Nova 3 - Resource - Remove Button - "Update & Continue Editing"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I cannot find where to remove one of the buttons on the edit Resource page.

The button I want to remove is the one labeled:

> Update & Continue Editing

[image]

**Laravel Nova Resource**

```
class VehicleService extends Resource
{

    public static $model = \App\Models\VehicleService::class;

    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
        ];
    }

    public function fieldsForIndex(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return [
            BelongsTo::make('Vehicle', 'vehicle', 'App\Nova\Vehicle')
            ->rules('required')
            ->viewable(false),
        ];
    }

    public function fieldsForDetail(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        BelongsTo::make('Vehicle', 'vehicle', 'App\Nova\Vehicle')
        ->viewable(false),
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we have some code please ?

Comment: @JonathanDelean I have updated the question to include the Laravel Resource code as well as an image of the edit form button I want to remove

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no conditionals in the Nova source to show / hide that button.

But there are dusk attributes for test purposes that you can hook onto.

Adding a [custom nova theme](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/themes.html) will include a css file you can add this too:

```css
[dusk="update-and-continue-editing-button"] {
    display: none 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, this worked great and using similar selectors I was able to hide some of the other buttons.

Comment: Or specify it with:
`
button[dusk="update-and-continue-editing-button"] {
            display: none;
        }
`